# Nodejs: Error bad rs block @ typeNumber:1/errorCorrectLevel:undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, whatsapp, whatsapp-web

Estoy tratando de enviar mensajes desde Node.js a whatsapp usando la liberaria whatsapp-web.js, estoy siguiendo un tutorial en YT de @LeiferMendez(excelente Youtuber) pero cuando quise crear el qr-code recibi el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es mi app.js**

```
import { writeFile, existsSync } from 'fs';
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import ora from 'ora';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import { Client } from 'whatsapp-web.js';
//import SESSION_FILE_PATH from './session.json'
import pkg from 'qrcode-terminal';
const { generate } = pkg;
//const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
//const chalk = require('chalk');


const SESSION_FILE_PATH = JSON.parse(
    await readFile(
        new URL('./session.json',
            import.meta.url)
    )
);

//const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';
let client;
let sessionData;


const withSession = () => {
    const spinner = ora(`Cargando ${chalk.yellow('Verified session with Whatsapp...')}`);
    sessionData = SESSION_FILE_PATH;
    spinner.start();

    client = new Client({
        session: sessionData
    })

    client.on('ready', () => {
        console.log('Client is ready!');
        spinner.stop();
    })

    client.on('auth_failure', () => {
        spinner.stop();
    })

    client.initialize();
}

//Crear qr para enlazar el punto origen
const withOutSession = () => {

    console.log('not session saved');
    client = new Client();
    client.on('qr', qr => {
        console.log(qr);
        generate(qr, { small: true });
    });


    client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
        //Guardamos credenciales de session para usar luego
        sessionData = session;
        writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    })

    client.initialize();
}

(existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) ? withSession(): withOutSession();
```

Adjunto mi package.json en un repo:

https://github.com/IzliaB/packagejson-whatsappEnd/blob/main/package.json

Según estuve leyendo este error sucede porque después de una cierta cantidad de caracteres, el código QR ya no se muestra en pantalla. En si el ejercicio busca si ya hay un registro o una sesión creada, la cual se almacena en un session.json entonces el app busca en el archivo de no ser asi, se genera el qr, pero no se si es que hay un limite para realizarlo o algo así ¿ustedes que opinan? ¿conocen del porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la línea `const { generate } = pkg;`

Este código funciona bien:

```
import { Client } from 'whatsapp-web.js';
import qrcode from 'qrcode-terminal';

let client = new Client();

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.initialize();
```

El resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo la idea porque `const { generate } = pkg` crea el error

Comment: Mil gracias @SergeyL eso era, creo que tiene que ver con las importaciones, ya que antes de venir aqui me estuvo dando problemas en ello también. Nuevamente, gracias,

Comment: No quiero abusar, pero fijate que ahora me tira el error "The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL" y el error me lo tira en la linea "( writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err))" ¿Estaré tratando correctamente el archivo? Es que, yo le agregué una función Json.parse para leer el archivo y no te sabría decir si allí esta el confilict al querer escribir en el archivo. Porque el error sucede justo cuando ha leido el codigo qr y quiere "almacenar" la sesión y escribirla en el .Json